# Как реализовать вектор на одном указателе?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вектор

На трех указателях ясно, но ни как не могу придумать как реализовать вектор на одном указателе, не задействовав для хранение оставшихся двух указателей выделенную память. Но говорят такой вариант есть.

Comment: хотябы  напишите ваш вектор, чтобы вам могли помочь с реализацией

Comment: Вы про какой vector ? Который std::vector ?

Comment: Вариант по указателю кроме данных хранить еще два указателя (или два размера, скажем) - не годится?

Comment: Во-первых, с чего вы взяли, что нужно именно "три указателя"? Указатель нужен только один, плюс два размера. Во-вторых, нет, просто "на одном указателе" вектор реализовать невозможно. Хранить размеры придется в любом случае. Можно, наверное, пользуясь особенностями платформы, обойтись одним размером вместо двух, но это - предел.

Comment: Спасибо, понял что не верно ставил себе вопрос, теперь стало понятно.

Comment: Как бы совсем только на одном указателе действительно сложно сделать вектор (памяти не хватит), но никто не мешает выделить на 4-8 байт больше. Просто сам вектор будет начинаться не с нулевой позиции. А первые байты будут использоваться для хранения размера/емкости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно "Pointer to implementation":

```
template<class T>
class MyVector
{
public: 
    MyVector()
       : data(0)
    {
    }
    ~MyVector()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data->size; ++i) {
           data[i].~T()
        }
    }
    void resize(size_t new_size)
    {
        struct AlignedData : public Data // структура для правильного учета выравнивания
        {
            T dummy_object;
        };
        void * new_data_mem = malloc(sizeof(AlignedData) + sizeof(T) * (new_size-1)); 
        Data * new_data = new(new_data_mem) Data;
        new_data->mem = &(static_cast<AlignedData*>(new_data_mem)->dummy_object);

        // либо перемещение старых
        for (auto i = 0; i < old_size; ++i) {
            new (&new_data->mem[i]) T(std::move(data->mem[i])); // <- перемещаем элемент в новую память
        }
        // либо инициализация новых элементов
        for (auto i = old_size; i < new_size; ++i) {
            new (&new_data->mem[i]) T; // <- инициализация элементов массива
        }
        // либо удаление лишних элементов
        for (auto i = new_size; i < old_size; ++i) {
            new_data->mem[i].~T();
        }

        data = new_data;
    }
private:
    Data
    {
        size_t size;
        size_t capacity;
        T * mem;
    };
    Data * data; // <== один указатель
};
```

Тут только идея. Возможны ошибки в синтаксисе и нет проверок ошибок и прочего.